# Numix GTK theme removes the "Unity Boxes"

Tags: unity, themes

Firstly, yes, I am aware this is a feature of the theme however I personally find it, well, ugly. My question is basically if there is anyway to reverse this and keep the boxes while still using the theme. I know I'd need to remove .svg files from the theme in my files, but im unsure which ones need to be removed. Any help would be great :)

[image]

Comment: Errr... could you add a screenshot? Also, how did you install the theme (through apt, [DevianART](http://www.deviantart.com/?qh=&section=&q=numix), etc)

Comment: Photo has been added to the question. And I installed the theme through apt-get using the numix repository .

Comment: Are the boxes on the menu bar part of the theme? I thought they were hard coded in

Comment: they are harcoded in, but it seems that the theme can set the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This very simply seems to be because some of the files in `/usr/share/themes/Numix Daily/unity' override background of the 'boxes' the launcher. The quick *(and fairly messy way)* is to run this to move the folder:

```
sudo mv '/usr/share/themes/Numix Daily/unity' '/usr/share/themes/Numix Daily/unityX'
```

A slightly better way is to make a backup copy of the `unity` folder, and remove those file beginning with `launcher` (I guess those cause the problem):

```
sudo cp -r '/usr/share/themes/Numix Daily/unity' '/usr/share/themes/Numix Daily/unity-backup'
sudo rm '/usr/share/themes/Numix Daily/unity/launcher*'
```

A better way to this would be to selectively remove the relevant files (it should use the default ones then - the square ones seem to set the launcher box backgrounds), or to edit the files.

To edit the files, you can use 'Inkscape' - if you want to do it without running inkscape as root (if you do, use `gksu`), you can change the permissions of the theme directory instead:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER '/usr/share/themes/Numix Daily/unity'
```

This is also useful if you don't want to use terminal or Nautilus as root to remove the files.

Note, keeping backup files makes life easy, and you probably need to logout and login again to see changes.

---

By the way, here is a screenshot of it working having moved the `unity` directory and logged out and logged in again (with Numix circle icon theme):

[image: screenshot]

Its quite a nice theme :D
(nice idea of having the waste-basket icon as a recycling icon :)